# Bash: Reading Output to a String with Special Characters

Tags: bash, sed, tshark

I'm using TShark to read TCP streams of a PCAP into a file of a set format. My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
OUT="*/temp/Temp.txt"
NEW="\"REQ:"
i=0
echo "Generating conversations..."
echo ""  > $OUT
while [ "$COUNT" != 1 ]
do
    BLOCK="$(tshark -r */browser.pcap -q -z follow,tcp,ascii,$i)"
    SUB=$(echo "$BLOCK" | sed -n '5p')
    PORT=${SUB##*:}
    BLOCK="${BLOCK//$'\t'/\"RES:}"
    BLOCK=$(echo "$BLOCK" | tail -n +6)
    BLOCK=$(echo "$BLOCK" | head -n -1)
    COUNT=$(echo "$BLOCK" | wc -l)
    BLOCK=$(echo "$BLOCK" | awk '{print $j"\""}')
    j=1
    while [ $j -lt $(($COUNT+2)) ]
    do
        CHECK=$(echo "$BLOCK" | sed $j'q;d')
        PREF=${CHECK:0:5}
        if [ "$PREF" != "\"RES:" ]; then
            CHECK=$NEW$CHECK
            BLOCK=$(echo "$BLOCK" | sed $j's/.*/'$CHECK'/')
        fi
        j=$(($j+1))
    done
    if [ "$COUNT" != 1 ]; then
        echo ""  >> $OUT
        echo "\$" >> $OUT
        echo "tag = \"gen."$i"\"" >> $OUT
        echo "port = \""$PORT"\"" >> $OUT
        echo "base = \"TCP\"" >> $OUT
        echo "payloads:" >> $OUT
        echo "$BLOCK" >> $OUT
        echo "Generated conversation "$i
    fi
    i=$(($i+1))
done
echo "Generation complete!"
```

When I run this, I get the following error for each conversation read:

```
> sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unterminated `s' command
```

I believe the problem lies in the call to TShark on line 9. Originally I used the "raw" argument for the command, which outputs raw hex data. This worked and output correctly. However, my task requires outputting ASCII data. Changing "raw" to "ascii" (both recognized by TShark) causes the aforementioned errors. I believe this is because the ASCII data in the read packets contains special characters; a small piece of data generated by line 9 in command line is:

```
..7.<.......Y.|.$.......2...W...v.'#
```

My question is are the special characters in the ASCII data I'm parsing causing the sed errors? If so, how could I make bash ignore them? Thanks!

Edit- I am ultimately trying to get the output of this TShark command, which looks like this...

```
===================================================================
Follow: tcp,raw
Filter: tcp.stream eq 4
Node 0: 10.211.55.3:58733
Node 1: 157.127.239.146:80
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
    485454502f312e3120333034204e6f74204d6f6469666965640d0a446174653a204672692c203234204a756c20323031352031343a33303a353520474d540d0a457870697265733a204672692c203234204a756c20323031352031353a35313a343120474d540d0a43616368652d436f6e74726f6c3a207075626c69632c206d61782d6167653d373230300d0a566172793a204163636570742d456e636f64696e670d0a436f6e6e656374696f6e3a20636c6f73650d0a5669613a20312e31206e657070737730390d0a0d0a
===================================================================
```

...into a custom format for a program to read. The above output is in the working raw hex data format. The custom format looks like this for the corresponding conversation:

```
$
tag = "gen.4"
port = "58733"
base = "TCP"
payloads:
"REQ: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"
"RES: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"
"REQ: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"
"RES:485454502f312e3120333034204e6f74204d6f6469666965640d0a446174653a204672692c203234204a756c20323031352031343a33303a353520474d540d0a457870697265733a204672692c203234204a756c20323031352031353a35313a343120474d540d0a43616368652d436f6e74726f6c3a207075626c69632c206d61782d6167653d373230300d0a566172793a204163636570742d456e636f64696e670d0a436f6e6e656374696f6e3a20636c6f73650d0a5669613a20312e31206e657070737730390d0a0d0a"
```

Comment: Quote the expansion of `$CHECK` (in general **always** quote your variable expansions) and that will solve part of your problem. You will still have problems with slashes/etc. in the value of `$CHECK` because `sed` can't tell the difference there. Using `awk` might make some of that easier. That all being said this seems like it cannot possibly be the right approach to your goal here. Perhaps if you explained the underlying task you might get more appropriate help for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell bash to not interpret metacharacters by quoting the variable expansion:

```
sed $j's/.*/'"$CHECK"'/'
```

In fact, there is no reason to use single quotes in the above, so you could just double-quote the entire command argument:

```
sed "${j}s/.*/$CHECK/"
```

However, neither of the above will tell *sed* to avoid interpreting special characters in the replacement part of the `s` command, so if `$CHECK` contains a <kbd>/</kbd>, then that will prematurely terminate the replacement.

So the question really is, is there a better way of accomplishing this:

```
BLOCK=$(echo "$BLOCK" | sed $j's/.*/'$CHECK'/')
```

Apparently, the goal is to replace line `$j` of the value of `$BLOCK` with the value of `$CHECK`. One way to do this, using `awk`:

```
BLOCK="$(awk -v repl="$CHECK" 'NR==$j{print repl;next}1')"
```

---

#### Notes:

1. Although I didn't fix it in my example, it is very bad style to use ALL CAPS for shell variables. Normally, shell variables in ALL CAPS are reserved for use as known exported variables by bash or system utilities (eg. `$PATH`; `$IFS`; `$TERM`; etc.). Your own variables should be lower-case to avoid conflicts.
2. The full loop that the command is excerpted from could probably be all implemented more efficiently and more cleanly (and more understandably) in `awk`. Based on the sample output, the following would probably work:

   ```
   echo "Generating conversations..."
   i=0
   while 
       tshark -r */browser.pcap -q -z follow,tcp,ascii,$i |
       awk -v idx=$i -v '
         NR==4 { n = split($0, a, /:/); port = a[n]; }
         NR<6  { next; }
         /^=========/ { exit port != 0; }
         port  { print "$"
                 printf "tag = \"gen.%d\"" idx
                 print "port = \"%s\"" port
                 print "base = \"TCP\""
                 print "payloads:"
                 port = 0
               }
         /^\t/ { printf "\"RES:%s\"" substr($0, 2) "\""; next; }
               { printf "\"REQ:%s\"" $0 "\""; }
       ' >> $OUT;
   do
       echo "Generated conversation "$i
   done
   echo "Generation complete!"
   ```

   I didn't try it. It may well be buggy. I don't understand the termination condition, so I just made a guess. I'm not sure if you really meant to extract the port number from line 5 (as in the code) or line 4 (as in the example.)

Comment: The line in question is to edit the $j line of $BLOCK and add a "REQ:" prefix. This is only done if there is not already a "RES:" prefix for that line. Thanks, I'll see if I can get that to work.

Comment: @user2741375: Are you doing that for every line?

Comment: Yes, I've added a bit more to the original question which shows the overall goal if that helps.

Comment: @user2741375: Are you certain that the request and response lines never contain newlines or tabs?

Comment: Yes, all data is output by TShark in one line per request or response. Tabs are only put before response lines to indicate that they are responses, and I replace those tabs with the "RES:" prefix.